# Why is this implementation of bubble sort significantly slower than expected?

Tags: python, performance, sorting

I have the following code that I implemented, but I don't know why the "fast" bubble sort I thought would run faster actually run slower than expected. In the first implementation, I think I am wasting a lot of time checking whether each array is sorted, which takes O(n) time. But in the second implementation, I am checking whether the array is sorted as I swap it, and so why does the second implementation run slower than I thought?

Do assignments take up more time than iterating through the list entirely?

```
def check_sorted(A):
    for i in xrange(1, len(A)):
        if A[i] < A[i-1]:
            return False

    return True

def bubble_sort(A):
    while not check_sorted(A):
        for i in xrange(1, len(A)):
            if A[i] < A[i-1]:
                A[i], A[i-1] = A[i-1], A[i]

    return A

def bubble_sort_fast(A):
    swap = True
    while swap:
        swap = False
        for i in xrange(1, len(A)):
            if A[i] < A[i-1]:
                A[i], A[i-1] = A[i-1], A[i]
                swap = True
    return A

A = list(reversed(range(5000)))
start_time = time.time()
A = bubble_sort(A)
print 'time_elapsed:', time.time() - start_time

A = list(reversed(range(5000)))
start_time = time.time()
A = bubble_sort_fast(A)
print 'time_elapsed:', time.time() - start_time


time_elapsed: 2.20229792595
time_elapsed (fast bubble sort): 2.38038301468
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, for me `bubble_sort_fast` is very slightly faster.

Comment: That is strange. I have even swapped the orders of the calls and still found that the fast bubble sort is slower.

Comment: You should use the `timeit` module if you want to get an accurate measure of the relative differences.

Comment: Actually, it looks like `bubble_sort_fast` is faster in Python 3 and slower in Python 2.

Comment: might be related to the reversed order. Try with different array numbers just in case

Comment: How do I use the timeit module in this case? It seems the code is too bulky to be included. Also, I tested with python 3 and see a smaller relative difference, but python 3 is slower by nearly 70% for both calls. For what it's worth, I'm using an AMD CPU and not an Intel one. Not sure if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the "fast" one is doing a lot more work. Add counters to see how often they're doing what the other one isn't doing:

```
def check_sorted(A):
    for i in xrange(1, len(A)):
        global slow_checks; slow_checks += 1              # <== Added this
        if A[i] < A[i-1]:
            return False
    return True

def bubble_sort_fast(A):
    swap = True
    while swap:
        swap = False
        for i in xrange(1, len(A)):
            if A[i] < A[i-1]:
                A[i], A[i-1] = A[i-1], A[i]
                swap = True
                global fast_marks; fast_marks += 1        # <== Added this
    return A
```

You'll find that `slow_checks` ends up as 9998 while `fast_marks` ends up as 12497500. That's a lot more. To be precise, that's 5000 * 4999 / 2, the total number of swaps in the original data.

Why is `slow_checks` so small? Well, because from one bubble-iteration to the next, your list evolves like this:

```
Start:                  [4999, 4998, 4997, 4996, 4995, ...
After bubbling 4999 up: [4998, 4997, 4996, 4995, 4994, ...
After bubbling 4998 up: [4997, 4996, 4995, 4994, 4993, ...
After bubbling 4997 up: [4996, 4995, 4994, 4993, 4992, ...
After bubbling 4996 up: [4995, 4994, 4993, 4992, 4991, ...
...
After bubbling 4 up:    [3, 2, 1, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ...
After bubbling 3 up:    [2, 1, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ...
After bubbling 2 up:    [1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ...
After bubbling 1 up:    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ...
```

As you can see, `check_sorted` can always `return False` after just looking at the first two values! Except for the very last time you ask it, because then it goes through the entire list and finds it's sorted. So 4999 times it does just one check and then one time it does 4999 checks, for an overall total of 9998 checks.

My whole code: https://repl.it/repls/SnarlingHotpinkNatterjacktoad